# Git-Bash, how to modify environment variable

Tags: environment-variables, git-bash

I have an environment variable which contains:

```
    C:\\Users\\u49100\\OneDrive\\Documents\\CA20-4021_BUILD_1.0.876\\Name\\sc_app
```

I want to modify the environment variable in a script stripping:

```
    C:\\Users\\u49100\\
```

So the result can be assigned to a new variable:

```
    OneDrive\\Documents\\CA20-4021_BUILD_1.0.876\\Name\\sc_app
```

Is there a way to do something like the following:

```
   NEW_VARIABLE=$FULL_DIR - $DIR_PREFIX
```

Where $FULL_DIR would contain the full directory and $DIR_PREFIX would contain the prefix at the start of the directory to remove.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of searching and some playing around I've found the following:

To get the length in characters of an environment variable:

```
    echo ${#VARNAME}
```

To get a sub-string from an environment variable:

```
    echo ${VARNAME:start:length}
```

Where "start" is base 0 and "length" is the number of characters to extract, length is optional and if not supplied then just use:

```
    echo ${VARNAME:start}
```

Will result in the entire content from the specified start offset.

So for my case the solution is:

```
    export NEW_VARIABLE=${FULL_DIR:${#DIR_PREFIX} + 1}
```

To search and replace any spaces with escaped spaces:

```
    export NEW_VARIABLE=${NEW_VARIABLE// /\\ }
```

The "//" is to replace all instances if just "/" then only the first is replaced, the "/\ " is the escaped version of the space character.